# Cakephp views are cached during development

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-2.4

I am developing an application in CakePHP 2.4.1 so I would like to turn all view cache off during development.

I changed the following items in config/core.php:

```
Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);

Configure::write('debug', 2);

if (Configure::read('debug') > 0) {
    $duration = '+1 seconds';
}
```

Despite the settings my layouts, elements and pages still seem to be cached for 30 seconds or so. Css file changes are not cached.

How can I prevent caching in my views?

Comment: define/explain "seem to be cached" - are you (explicitly) using view/element/full-page-view caching? If so the question is missing information. If not - you're probably looking at the wrong problem: cake doesn't do any caching by default. Check Http headers =).